# Ubuntu blank screen after login

Tags: ubuntu

I have a laptop running Ubuntu 13.10.  It was running fine till yesterday when I installed OpenCV 2.4 using Synaptic (if that is of any relevance since there is no other change in configuration).  This morning, I powered it on and it comes to the screen asking for login, even showing my background correctly.  However, after I login, the screen goes blank.  I can see the mouse cursor and it moves when I use the trackpad, but I am unable to do anything else.  I am not able to start terminal window or anything else because I do not have any icon.  From the login screen, I tried to change to Gnome (instead of Ubuntu default) but still, had no luck.  Can someone please help?

There should be a command to go into non-GUI mode but I cannot recall that either.

The output from `lspci | grep VGA` is

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Mobile GM965/GL960 Integrated Graphics Controller (primart) (rev 0c)
```

Looks like it is unable to load `Plugin opengl` which must be because of my install of OpenCV.

`apt-cache policy nvidia`

```
nvidia:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: (none)
  Version table:
```

`apt-cache policy fglrx`

```
fglrx:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 2:13.101-0ubuntu3
  Version table:
     2:13.101-0ubuntu3 0
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy/restricted amd64 Packages
```

If it is of any help, I typed the command `glxinfo` and got the error:

```
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0".
Error: couldn't find RGB GLX visual or fbconfig
```

Comment: Are you able to use another machine to `ssh` into your laptop, by any chance? Maybe that will help you?

Comment: Cay you get into a tty? (Ctrl+Alt+F1)? If so try running `DISPLAY=:0 unity --replace` or just `DISPLAY=:0 unity`.

Comment: I was able to go in using Ctrl+Alt+F1.  I tried `startx` but it gave me an error sau=ying extension GLX missing.  When I tried @Seth's suggestion, it gave me a bunch of errors with `compiz (decor) - Warn: requested a pixmap type decoration when compositing isn't available` followed by `Xlib: extension "GLX" missing on display ":0"`

Comment: Can you *edit* the output of `lspci | grep VGA` into your question please?

Comment: @Seth, I just updated the question with the suggested edit.

Comment: Now can you do `apt-cache policy nvidia*` and `apt-cache policy fglrx`?

Comment: @Seth Thanks for supporting me; I have updated the question with the edits.

Comment: That's useful, however there was supposed to be an asterisk (`*`) after `nvidia`. We're checking to make sure that you don't have any graphics drivers installed that shouldn't be there (since you're using an intel card). It would also be useful if you could upload the contents of `/var/log/Xorg.0.log` to a site like [Ubuntu Paste](http://paste.ubuntu.com/) so I could look at it. btw, did you try switching back to tty7 after running the `unity` command? Ctrl+Alt+F7.

Comment: Switching to tty7 after unity did not help.  I have three nvidia drivers installed: nvidia-common (version 1:0.2.83), nvidia-settings-319-updates (version 319.60-0ubuntu1), and nvidia-319-updates (version 319.60-0ubuntu1).  Pasted the Xorg.0.log file at http://paste.ubuntu.com/6624674/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After examining your [Xorg.0.log](http://paste.ubuntu.com/6624674/), it appears that Xorg is attempting to load the glx module with [the nvidia drivers](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/106378/ubuntu-blank-screen-after-login?noredirect=1#comment163301_106378), and since you don't have an Nvidia card it's failing to load.  Removing the Nvidia packages should solve your issue:

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia-common nvidia-settings-319-updates nvidia-319-updates
```

Then restart.

In case you're interested, here are the important lines in your `Xorg.0.log`:

```
[    26.590] (II) "glx" will be loaded by default.  
...  
[    30.675] (II) LoadModule: "glx"
[    30.675] (II) Loading /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/xorg/extra-modules/libglx.so
[    31.137] (II) Module glx: vendor="NVIDIA Corporation"
[    31.137]    compiled for 4.0.2, module version = 1.0.0
[    31.137]    Module class: X.Org Server Extension
[    31.137] (II) NVIDIA GLX Module  319.60  Wed Sep 25 14:24:11 PDT 2013
[    31.138] Loading extension GLX  
...  
[    31.250] (EE) Failed to initialize GLX extension (Compatible NVIDIA X driver not found)
```

[This Ubuntu Forums thread](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1741783) was very useful in figuring this out.

Comment: This worked.  I have a GUI.  However, I do not have any decorations on the windows, nor do I have the tabs containing commands to be run on the side (toolbar).  Can you suggest what do I need to get the toolbar back?  And my window decorations?

Comment: I am able to use the machine nicely by changing over to Gnome desktop but cannot use the Ubuntu default.  Any suggestions?

Comment: @unxnut Are you experiencing something like [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/17381/unity-doesnt-load-no-launcher-no-dash-appears)? If not, a screenshot would help :)

Comment: Not exactly.  I have all the icons of items on my desktop but that is pretty much it.  If I double click on an icon, it opens up the document appropriately.  However, I do not have any surrounding border and so, cannot minimize it.  I also do not have a toolbar on the side.  For now, I am using the Gnome desktop but I liked Unity better.

Comment: What you are describing seems exactly like that question. The launcher and dash don't appear, but everything else works.